# Insert if something changed other than specific column

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, trigger, insert

I have a table with many columns but my snippet is simplified. I have the trigger shown below but how can I have it so that nothing is inserted if *only* the `created_at` column has changed?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[t_upd_insert]
ON [dbo].[Player]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;


BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.Changes (
            [name]
            [created_at]
       )
SELECT 
            ins.[name],
            ins.[created_at]                
FROM INSERTED ins
```

I could do a `WHERE name != ins.[name]` for each column but there are a lot of columns and tables that need this; is there a shorter syntax?

**EDIT**
 I've tried adding

```
WHERE
      [name] != ins.[name] OR 
      [age] != ins.[age]
      ....
```

but that doesn't work either. I thought that would be the naive method but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can use either `UPDATE()` or `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` functions for this.

Comment: Just note that those don't tell you if the value has actually changed as a result of the update.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[t_upd_insert]
ON [dbo].[Player]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;


BEGIN
IF (update(name))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.Changes (
            [name]
            [created_at]
       )
  SELECT 
            ins.[name],
            ins.[created_at]                
  FROM INSERTED ins
END
```

Comment: This tells you that `name` was one of the columns in the `SET` list, but not whether the actual value has changed.

Comment: True if you really need to know if the value changed then I don't see other option than looking in the inserted table.

Comment: I've updated my question showing how I'm looking in the inserted table but even that isn't working. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

I cross-posted this to Stackoverflow and found a [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38146948/369784), even if it meant having to type out the column names (which explains why my `WHERE` clause didn't work)

```
SELECT ins.[name], ins.[created_at]                
FROM INSERTED ins JOIN
     DELETED del
     ON ins.id = del.id
WHERE del.[name] <> ins.[name] OR 
      del.[age] <> ins.[age];
```

I won't accept the answer here for now in case someone has a way of not having to type every column name that could change instead of just the `created_at` column.